# Can you spot this PHP error? I'm stumped

Tags: php

**Here's the scenerio of what is happening in the script:**

- Session is start.
- `$id` is set to a number (tournament ID number).

**Result:**

- User SESSION vars are reset with the ID number and the ID number's respective user data. Essentially logging the user in under a different account.

**Troubleshooting:**

- Renaming `$id` to `$tid` stops the glitch.
- Not starting the session (`session_start()`) stops the glitch.

**Thought Process:**

- $id must overwrite similar variable which is inside a block which contains:
  `if(isset( $_SESSION['someVar'] )) {
  $id = "some Value";
  }`

Since `$id` is only overwritten when session is started.

**The Problem:**

- There is no block of code that uses that syntax.

Here's the call stack.

jointourney.php

```
<?
session_start();
$id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : false;
include("html.php");
?>
```

html.php

```
<?
if(session_id() == '') session_start();
if(!function_exists('isLogged')) include("includes/islogged.inc.php");
include("includes/autologin.inc.php");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM config WHERE name='shutdown'");
$query = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$shutdown = end($query);
if(!class_exists('ban')) include("class/ban.class.php");
$ban = new ban();
if(isLogged()){
    $ban->setUsername($_SESSION['username']);
}
$user_level = (isset($_SESSION['user_level'])) ? $_SESSION['user_level'] : "0";
$ban->setIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if((strlen($shutdown) > 0 || $ban->isBanned()) && $user_level == 0 && strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) != "/login.php"){
    if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) != "/error.php"){
        header("Location: ./error.php");
    }
}
?>
```

islogged.inc.php
File not needed, no variables set: only returns true/false.

autologin.inc.php

```
<?
if(!class_exists('login')) include("./class/login.class.php");
$login = new Login();
    if(isset($_COOKIE['username'],$_COOKIE['password']) && !$login->isLoggedIn()){
        $login->setUsername($_COOKIE['username']);
        $login->setPasswordDirect($_COOKIE['password']);
        if(!$login->_error){
            $login->processLogin();
        }
}
?>
```

As you see, there is absolutely no place where jointourney.$id can overwrite - since there is no other variable called `$id` being used.
Note: There are no variables that are being set globally (i.e. global `$id`)

I do not understand why this is happening, are you guys able to figure this out? Everything you see here is exactly how it looks (minus HTML).

Comment: Would you happen to have `register_globals` turned `On`?

Comment: Do you use session_register at any time? (shouldn't have anything to say with register_globals Off)

Comment: Nevermind - I was looking at my localhost, not the testing server - yes register_globals is on

Comment: This isn't your problem, but as a side note, you should use a full URL in your `Location:` headers to be compliant with the RFCs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn `register_globals` `Off` in your server's `php.ini`.

Comment: Thanks, but this host does not allow access to change PHP.ini - Using `php_flag register_globals off` in .htaccess would still work, right?

Comment: @TurdPile: So I hear - it's never worked for me, but maybe you'll have better luck :)

Comment: apparently not - gives my website ISE 500 LOL

Comment: @TurdPile: Try putting a `php.ini` with only the line `register_globals = Off` inside the directory that contains your PHP file. If it works, darn, because it's not inherited and you have to copy it to every subdirectory too.

Comment: Good thing all my processing scripts that read environment variables are all in one folder :) Looks like it worked.